# printf (with %n) raises fatal error.

Tags: c, printf

Here is a very simple code that I'm trying to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int x;
    printf( "TEST%n", &x );
}
```

I expect x to become equal 4 instead I'm getting fatal error.

I use Visual Studio 2008 and Windows XP.

During execution I get window saying `"Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error..."`
Then debugger opens up dbghook.c file with `_CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK` function.

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the & for the x ?

Comment: @Amir Because the `"%n"` format code *writes* to its argument.

Comment: You need to enable `%n` by [_set_printf_count_output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782)

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`. (Microsoft's compiler happens to accept `void main()`, but there's no good reason to use it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MSDN format type page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Security Note   The `%n` format is inherently insecure and is disabled by default; if `%n` is encountered in a format string, the invalid parameter handler is invoked as described in [Parameter Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). To enable `%n` support, see [`_set_printf_count_output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: How is it "inherently insecure"?

Comment: @KeithThompson: when combined with another security issue - using a user-provided string as the format string - a carefully crafted format string with "%n" can write to a user controlled location on the stack.  They may be other issues as well.  For an example, see http://seclists.org/bugtraq/1999/Sep/328

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int x;
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

You are using incorrect syntex for printf.Other thing is "&" is used for scanf.

Comment: The OP is trying to use `%n`, which does require a pointer value.