# printf() precision

Tags: c, printf, format-string

```
char buf[10];
int counter, x = 0;
snprintf (buf, sizeof buf , "%.100d%n", x, &counter); 
printf("Counter: %d\n", counter)
```

I am learning about precision with printf. With %.100d%n, the precision here gives 100 digits for rendering x.

What I don't understand is why would the counter be incremented to 100, although only 10 characters are actually written to the buffer?

Comment: The `100` you're getting is the size that is _actually_ needed to printf the whole thing without truncation. Anyway I'd not use `%n` alltogether (it's not implemented on all platforms), but rather use the return value of `snprintf`.

Comment: Take a look at what is actually written to your `buf`

Comment: @Jabberwocky %n isn't implemented on windows unless you use `gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`

Comment: it's the design of %n specifier, which can also be used as a security hole

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `%n` being a security hole [isn't really a strong argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421115/printf-with-n-raises-fatal-error).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957216/why-does-printf-specifier-format-n-not-work/54959487#comment96680630_54959487  It seems more like just another Microsoftian non-portable incompatibility.

Comment: I didn't mean it like that. Windows printf doesn't support %n because windows native printf sucks.

Answer (score 1):

The ten bytes written to `buf` are 9 spaces and 1 `'\0'` (zero terminator), `counter` is assigned the value `100` for 99 spaces and 1 `'0'` (digit zero).

```
   buf <== "         "
%.100d <== "          .....   0"
```

**Note that `buf` is incomplete: it does not have a `'0'`.**

Comment: I think OP wants to know why the counter gets the required value when the buffer is too short.